# DIV becomes invisble but remains clickable when scaling content only in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scaletransform

I have a situation where a DIV element seems to randomly become invisble while remaining clickable. It happens only in chrome and I can't trace the problem back to a specific css setting. I was hoping that one of you recognizes the problem and give suggestions as to what may be the cause.

On my [webpage](http://www.stefanbruins.nl/XIMPEL/test_files/ximpel_test.htm) I have an example. The page shows a youtube video playing and has an absolute positioned div over it at the bottom which contains the controls. The controls become invisble when the window gets above a certain size.

**Reproducing the bug**

- Only happens in chrome.
- Open the page (video starts playing). If no controls are shown then resize the page smaller until the controls become visible. If controls are already visible then resize the page bigger until the controls disappear.
- When the controls disappear they are invisble but can still be clicked (hovering them makes the cursor change).
- It seems as though the video is above the buttons causing the buttons to become invisble, but somehow they can still be clicked.

**Structure of the page**

The structure of the page looks like this :

```
<div class="container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" >
    <div class="wrapper" style="width: 1080px; height: 720px;">
        <div class="player">
            // videos element.
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="control"></div>
            <div class="control"></div>
            <div class="control"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

- The container is stretched to take up 100% width and 100% height of the screen.
- The wrapper element is positioned absolute and has a fixed width/height of 1080*720 but is transformed (scaled) such that its size becomes as large as possible while fitting inside the container and while maintaining aspect ratio. This scaling is done on window resize.
- The controls are absolutely positioned over the player element. The entire controls div disappears (not just the individual control elements). However when applying css mouseover effects they still trigger. And onclick events still fire.
- The bug does not happen when displaying images isntead of video.

I know its not much to go on without the full code, but the whole page is built up using javascript and is quite a lot. I am just wondering if there are any know bugs with divs disappearing in chrome when using one or more of the following:

- Absolute positioned divs
- Transform-scale
- normal video elements / youtube video iframes (happens for both in my case)

**EDIT:**
Ok, I reproduced the problem in a minimal html/js page (see [here](http://www.stefanbruins.nl/test2.htm)). I could not put it on jsfiddle because you can't resize the output frame of jsfiddle enough to reproduce the bug. I traced down the problem and I found out that when I remove `overflow-x: hidden;` and `overflow-y: hidden;` from the player element that the controls DIV does not become invisble anymore. However, if I do that it means that when content overflows the player element it will not be hidden. Anyone has an idea why the overflow setting is causing the controls div to disappear but not become unclickable and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i found that the problem was caused by `overflow: hidden;` on the player element. By removing the `overflow: hidden;` setting the problem disapeared.

Instead of removing `overflow: hidden;` I could also use: `transform: translate3d( 0,0,0 );` on the .controls element and the .control elements.

However, I still don't know why this problem happens and why the above fixes it.

Comment: I just had the exact same issue in Chrome 70. And indeed, adding the transform fixed it...

Comment: Another confirmation: some combination of overflow: hidden and a scale transform caused disappearing elements in Chrome. Adding transform: translate3d( 0,0,0 ); to the element with overflow: hidden stopped the elements from disappearing. The problem happened in Chrome only (on Mac; didn't test Windows).